# What makes the reals a small set?

Tags: soft-question, real-numbers, ordered-fields

The following is more of a soft question than a concrete problem, but it haunts me for quite a while now.

The reals can be defined as the maximal Archimedean field. They are tiny in comparison to other sets; there are quite a lot of large sets. I find it counterintuitive that there are no Archimedean fields of arbitrary large cardinality. Why is this the case?

Note: I am not really asking for a proof of this fact. The ones I have seen (e.g. [here](https://choum.net/%7Echris/cours_et_notes/reals.pdf)) were perfectly fine, but they did not really give an intuitive reason, why larger sets cannot arise.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Intuitively, I see the Archimedean property as restricting how "long" the ordered set can be; we can "step past it" with countably many "steps". The field structure interacting with the order means that this also restricts how "fine" it can be, i.e. how many points lie between the "steps". It's all a bit wishy-washy I'm afraid, but that's why I find this result unsurprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an ordered field $F$ has cardinality $>|\mathbb{R}|$, then $\mathbb{N}$ has an upper bound in it.

Indeed, assume the contrary. Then $\mathbb{Q}$ is order-dense in $F$. So for $x \in F$, there is a sequence $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with $|x-q_n|<2^{-n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. No other element $y$ of $F$ can satisfy this with respect to $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (take $n$ with $2^{-n}<\frac{|x-y|}{2}$). So this yields a surjective map $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow F$, sending any irrelevant sequence to $0$ and sending sequences like $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to their limit. Since $|\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}|=|\mathbb{R}|$, this contradicts the assumption.

Now since $\mathbb{N}$ has an upper bound in $F$, it should have a least upper bound in $F$ if $F$ were complete. But for any upper bound $M$, we have $M-1>\mathbb{N}$, so there is no such supremum.

So to sum up: if $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded then the field is not complete, and if $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded then the field is small.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why completeness implies existence of least upper bounds ?

Comment: I thought you meant completeness as in having the least upper bound property. What did you mean?

Comment: You can define Cauchy sequences, since you have a notion of "neighbourhood of 0", and an algebraic operation of difference. Completeness would then mean that Cauchy sequences converge.

Comment: Then there are complete ordered fields of arbitrary cardinality. For instance in fields of hyperreal numbers, any Cauchy sequence indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ must be eventually constant, so it converges. Those fields can have large cardinalities.

Answer (score 1):

If an ordered field is archimedean and complete, then all its points are limits of points in $\mathbb{Q}$. This gives you a bound on the cardinality of the field.

In a sense, filling the gaps between the points of $\mathbb{Q}$ can only create so many new points.